# Stream data into ag-grid with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am attempting to use ag-grid in an application where events are streamed to the client.  Every event received should be added to the grid.  I am adding via  the `insertItemsAtIndex` method, and am getting multiple events per second.

Unfortunately ag-grid doesn't seem to handle this scenario very well.  The first 10 or so events are displayed promptly, but after that I only see chunks of events displayed after a delay.  The browser also completely bogs down to the point that it is unusable.

**Is there a better way to use ag-grid for streaming data?**  I have tried the other `addItems` method, I have removed any cell renderers, sorts, filters, etc. in order to try and keep it as lean as possible, but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is the enterprise feature of a [Viewport Row Model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-viewport/#gsc.tab=0). It's the exact thing that you are looking for. However, if you don't have that option, then I would suggest handling the addition of items outside of the grid, then updating the rows with what you create... that *might* be more optimized.

Comment: Thanks Jarod.  We do not have the enterprise options available.  Also, I'm not sure viewport is quite right.  My understanding of the viewport model is that it just shows different parts of data that already exists in a dataset, rather than allowing for continually scrolling data that is recently added.  Perhaps we need to restructure how we're getting events so we can work with that model better.  I did try adding rows outside the grid, without improvement.

Comment: @trumpsnare I created [this plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/R6ahoI0ZbtTLS2wSiuPi/) to test the limits of `insertItemsAtIndex` and it doesn't seem to have your reported issue, leading me to believe that the problem is with the network calls/sockets that you might have set up...

Comment: can't argue with that plunker.  Created my own to try and more closely replicate the actual scenario and it also seemed to work perfectly well.  Recreated the plunker in our actual environment and it was slow.  At this point we think it might be a hardware issue, the machines we run on are pretty underpowered.  Thanks for the help!